# TSLint и WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, tslint

Как включить автоисправление TSLint в WebStorm при сохранении? С ESLint`ом проблем не возникало

Answer (score 1):

Действия при сохранении вообще не поддерживаются платформой (главным образом потому, что одной из базовых особенностей IDE является автосохранение - т.е. файл может быть сохранен автоматически в любой момент, и у пользователя нет возможности это контролировать). См. [IDEABKL-6722](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6722). Поэтому никакого автоисправления на сохранении нет ни для TSLint, ни для ESLint.

если вы хотите автоматически запускать `tslint --fix` именно при **Save All**, вместо использования **Fix current file** (доступного по `Alt+Enter`), попробуйте сконфигурировать его в качестве [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/file-watchers.html), и выключите для него **immediate synchronization**: если эта опция выключена, watcher запускается только по **Save All**. Вот пример простейшей конфигурации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]